# How can you test for a DNS leak for an OpenVPN provider?

Tags: security, vpn, dns, openvpn, privacy

I'm currently using VPNBook with OpenVPN. I just recently learned about DNS leaking. Is there a way to scan for it?

Answer (score 1):

> OpenVPN won't assign server's DNS resolver(s) if you run it from
>   terminal. This is a known behavior and until OpenVPN developers fix
>   it, you have to run an external script to assign the DNS resolvers
>   once the tunnel is connected, and revert when disconnected. This
>   should work on Ubuntu, Debian, and any Debian based distros.
>
> **Step 1**
>
> First, you have to update the `.ovpn` profiles to run a script that
>   will assign a DNS resolver and restore your original resolver when
>   the VPN connection will shut-down. Add the following lines to the
>   `.ovpn` file:
>
> ```
> script-security 2  
> up updatedns.sh  
> down updatedns.sh
> ```
>
> Note that this applies if you run openvpn [server profile.ovpn] from
>   the current folder, not eg.
>
> ```
> openvpn /home/myself/Downloads/openvpn-profiles/server-location.ovpn
> ```
>
> If you run from different folder, you will have to include the full
>   path accordingly (also to the mass-update command below)
>
> To mass-update all `.ovpn` profiles in a folder, unzip the server
>   profiles, then from the same folder run:
>
> ```
> for filename in *.ovpn; do  echo -e "script-security 2\nup updatedns.sh\ndown updatedns.sh" >> $filename; done
> ```
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Get the updatedns.sh script:
>
> ```
> wget https://vpn.ac/configs/misc/updatedns.sh
> ```
>
> Run `chmod +x updatedns.sh to make it executable` Step 3
>
> Connect by running:
>
> ```
> openvpn ./[location-profile].ovpn
> ```
>
> Once connected, check [dnsleak test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/). It should report our DNS
>   resolvers.
>
> When you disconnect, the original `resolv.conf` will be restored.
>   If anything goes wrong it it doesn't restore properly (ie. openvpn
>   process killed), restore it manually by running:
>
> ```
> cp -a /etc/resolv.conf.orig /etc/resolv.conf
> ```

<sup>Source:[VPN.AC](https://forum.vpn.ac/discussion/13/running-openvpn-in-linux-terminal-with-no-dns-leaks)</sup>