# Can't set the openVPN without dns leaks

Tags: command-line, dns, openvpn

I found that I have leaks when I set my VPN through Terminal.
I found couple  thread and tried to use this method - [How can you test for a DNS leak for an OpenVPN provider?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560832/how-can-you-test-for-a-dns-leak-for-an-openvpn-provider)

I made everything, when I connect to my VPN its says that everything is okay but when I try to open any website they just doesn't load.

I'm able to use the VPN without this script

`script-security 2

up updatedns.sh

down updatedns.sh`
 
but I have DNS Leaks.

This is my .ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote de-dusseldorf.ra4wvpn.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

And down there is the Certificate.

I want to know why its not working and how can I fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: We are no wizard. You need to at least show your openvpn config here if you expect people to help

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it ;)

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it?